# Creating empty binary tree function

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am creating a binary tree program at the moment and I have implemented quite a few functions so far. I would now like to add a function to create an empty tree but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

As an example of what I have, here is my code for creating a tree with an initial value to store:

```
BST::BST() {
    root = nullptr;
}

void BST::createWithRoot(int key) {
    createWithRootPrivate(key, root);
}

void BST::createWithRootPrivate(int key, node* Ptr) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = createLeaf(key);
    }   
}

BST::node* BST::createLeaf(int key) {
    node* n = new node;
    n -> key = key;
    n -> left = nullptr;
    n -> right = nullptr;

    return n;
}
```

I had tried doing something like this, but unsurprisingly it didn't work:

```
BST::node* BST::createLeaf(int key) {
    node* n = new node;
    n -> key = nullptr;
    n -> left = nullptr;
    n -> right = nullptr;

    return n;
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm sure it's simple but I'm pretty new to C++ and binary trees.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: `node* n = new node;
    n -> key = nullptr;
    n -> left = nullptr;
    n -> right = nullptr;` - start by creating default constructor for `BST::node` for cleaner code.

Comment: I would use root == nullptr to indicate an empty tree. So creating that would just return nullptr...

Comment: @KlamerSchutte Thanks. That seems to be the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply add a void constructor method like this

```
BST::BST(){
    root = nullptr;// as says Klamer
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question with some code that I actually already have... Not sure if it does the same thing.